# posting fields from the model in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model Document.rb and in this I have created another class image:

```
 class Image
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :imageId, type: String

    field :srcDocumentId, type: Integer

    field :scopes, type: String

    field :teiId, type: String

    field :name , type: String

    field :headline, type: String

    field :description, type: String

    field :inBody, type: Boolean

    field :image, type: String

    field :internalUrl, type: String

    field :source, type: String

    field :ord, type: Integer

  end
```

and I have this:

```
 PdsBackend.document_images(external_id).each do |image|
 doc.images << Image.new(image)
 end
```

in the other class Document:

```
  class Document
    include Mongoid::Document

  field :external_document_id, type: String

  field :file_name, type: String

  embeds_one :image, class_name: 'Document::Image'
```

and in the pds_backend.rb I have defined this:

```
def document_images(document_id)
    with_login do
    expect_success { self.class.get("/image/#{document_id}")}
  end
end
```

while in the view when I want to display what I am getting from the backend:

```
   %h1.document__body= (@document.image)
```

I want to display name, headline and image string in the front-end but I don't know how to define image

Comment: Maybe the `meta` doesn't have any images, so you get an empty `Array`?

Comment: @engineersmnky probably that, so I edited my initial post, but now I don't even get the brackets. But I know now that I get some of these fields back if I define image like this `def image
    self.external_content['contentBody']
  end` but what I want is to get the name with headline display and the image string separately so that I can put it in an image tag